# Convert from BST to CST in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, datetime, timezone

I am converting time from BST to CST, It's working as expected for me.

```
string inputDate = "2209210940";
DateTime gmtTime = DateTime.ParseExact(inputDate, "yyMMddHHmm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
TimeZoneInfo gmtTimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("GMT Standard Time");
TimeZoneInfo centralTimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central Standard Time");
var time = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(gmtTime, gmtTimeZone, centralTimeZone);

bool isDayLightSavingTimeGMT = gmtTimeZone.IsDaylightSavingTime(new DateTime(2022, 09, 21, 09, 40, 00));
bool isDayLightSavingTimeCST = centralTimeZone.IsDaylightSavingTime(new DateTime(2022, 09, 21, 09, 40, 00));
```

I also have checked properties, both are in DayLightSavingTime now.

I also tested by changing the date time to 2201210940 (above both time zones are not in DayLightSaving that time), and this value also worked as expected.

I also have tested my changes by changing CEST to IST (there is no daylight saving concept in IST), which is also working as expected.

I am just curious to know if there is any case in which I am missing or if I need to handle it explicitly.

I am also curious to know that Is there a way to confirm whether the output is correct or now, for now, I am using this website to manually verify the times.

I am using .net 4.7.2

[image]

Comment: You have to make sure code works based on where and when the data was collected and not when program was running.  So you have to consider cases where data was collected in a different time zone from where the program was run.  And consider when the program and data were collected at different times like when data was collect in Day Light saving time and Program was run in Standard Time.

Comment: @jdweng times zones are fixed here in my case. They will always be BST and CST. And I’m not doing anything related to local culture. it’s given that input time is always in BST

Comment: You said you were curious to see if there were cases you didn't consider.  Data is often processed in different location and time zones (and at different Standard/Daylight times) from where/when code is processed.  It is a bug if you do not consider these conditions.

Comment: If your source and destination `TimeZone` are fixed, you can simply verify it with difference value (with DayLightSaving On and Off) with your custom function.

Comment: @DarshanFaldu I agree